# Lifting a char $p$ variety to char $0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, projective-space, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a finite field $k$ (say, $\mathbb F_p$), I would like to lift it to a projective scheme $X'$ over char $0$ ring $R$ (say $\mathbb Z$) with a surjective map $R \to k$ such that $X'_k \cong X$. I think the following should work:

There will be some $\mathbb P^n_k$ for which $X$ is defined as a closed subscheme by a homogeneous ideal $I \subset k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$. We can arbitrarily lift the generators of $I$ to polynomials in $R[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ and hence define a homogenous ideal $I'$ over $R$. Then, define $X'$ to be the closed subscheme defined by $I'$.

I would now like to show that the specialization of $X'$ to $k$ would recover $X$ but I don't think this is true because of the counterexample here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25337/lifting-varieties-to-characteristic-zero.

I think the problem is that we would end up getting a little bit more than $X$ but I am having a hard time figuring out why or finding an example where this happens. Any help?

Comment: The main problem is not that $X'_k\simeq X$ but that $X'$ will not be flat over $R$ in general. Actually, if $X$ is defined over $k$, it is in particular defined over $R$, but of course it is not flat over $R$. Indeed when you say that you want to lift arbitrarily the generators of $I$, you may produce conditions like $p=0$.

Comment: Yes, I see. The bit about $p=0$ helped a lot.